# Slim API doesn't respond to POST routing

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have spent the past few days integrating Slim API to handle some PHP web services. The first few services utilized GET which was straight forward and had no problems. However, when trying to integrate some POST methods, I am receiving no response from the service. I have tried even just a simple echo to see if the service is being called. In every case, there is no return. Code below, some of the methods have been removed for clarity.

Any reason the POST method is unresponsive? Thanks! viv

```
$app->get('/login/:un/:pw/:type','login');
$app->get('/browseMO/:prm1/:prm2', 'browseMedia');
$app->get('/usersReviews/:userID','usersReviews');
$app->get('/pubsReviews/:userID','pubsReviews');    
$app->get('/productReviews/:productID','getProductReviews');
$app->get('/productAvg/:productID','averageReviewsByOProduct');
$app->post('/userUpd','updateUserInfo');
$app->run();

function averageReviewsByOProduct($productID){
    reviews::getAvgReviewByProduct($productID);
}
function browseMedia($param1, $param2){
    browseMediaObjects::getMedia($param1, $param2);
}   
function updateUserInfo(){
    // $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    // $body = $request->getBody();
    echo "UPDATE CALLED"; // never reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an anonymous function in the slim post declaration and see if the function gets call. If it doesn't, it's something with slim. If it does, it's something with your code.

```
$app->post('/userUpd',function() use ($app) {
    echo 'Test';
});
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you are returning your data correctly. For instance the above returns data correctly for an AJAX call that expects a text string response.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this produces the same result :(

Comment: Then you need to look at your slim configuration and make sure you haven't turned something on or off by mistake

Comment: I've not done anything with the configuration and am just writing these services to support iOS applications (PHP not my specialty!). Can you give me any idea where to look for a problem?

Comment: Do do that you would need to show your slim code - from when you include it to when you end it.

Comment: One thing to check is slim debug mode. If set to true slim should send a nice exception message with a full trace

Comment: I assume that it is in debug mode, since for real errors i am getting the full trace and a helpful error message. For the POST calls in question, I get nothing--no errors and a blank screen